# JAVA Rest Assured IO XmlPath returns all elements values when xpath does not match any element?

Tags: java, xml, rest-assured

could any one point out why I get my XML's full values of all elements concatenated when I use an xpath that is not matching an element in the XML ?
I would expect an exception (i.e.: element not found) or a null value rather, am I missing something ?

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootElement>
    <topElement1>value 1</topElement1>
    <topElement2>value 2</topElement2>
    <topElement3 attribute="att3">
        <childElementA>value A</childElementA>
        <childElementB attribute="attB">value B</childElementB>
    </topElement3>
</rootElement>
```

Java:

```
String responseBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><rootElement><topElement1>value 1</topElement1><topElement2>value 2</topElement2><topElement3 attribute=\"att3\"><chileElementA>value A</chileElementA><chileElementB attribute=\"attB\">value A</chileElementA></topElement3></rootElement>";
String actual = new XmlPath(responseBody).get(xpath);
```

If I then call this code with different xpath which are not 'valid', the returned value is the text of all elements in the XML document. Examples:

```
new XmlPath(responseBody).getString("topElement1") -> "value 1value 2value Avalue B"
new XmlPath(responseBody).getString("nonExisting") -> "value 1value 2value Avalue B"
```

Unless I set a 'valid' path, of an existing element, then it returns only that element's value. Examples:

```
new XmlPath(responseBody).getString("rootElement.topElement1") -> value 1
new XmlPath(responseBody).getString("rootElement.topElement3.childElementB") -> value B
```

Why an xpath that is not matching an element returns the whole document's elements texts ?
Thanks

PS: with json, if the element is not found based on the xpath, an exception would be returned.